# Python str.translate VS str.replace

Tags: python

Why in ***Python*** `replace` is ~1.5x quicker than `translate`?

```
In [188]: s = '1 a  2'

In [189]: s.replace(' ','')
Out[189]: '1a2'

In [190]: s.translate(None,' ')
Out[190]: '1a2'

In [191]: %timeit s.replace(' ','')
1000000 loops, best of 3: 399 ns per loop

In [192]: %timeit s.translate(None,' ')
1000000 loops, best of 3: 614 ns per loop
```

Comment: I'm guessing you're not basing this on a single measurement, right?

Comment: It shows that he timed it out of 1000000 tests.

Comment: @Brobin Whoops. Good catch.

Comment: Assuming CPython, which is open source, have you considered actually *looking at the implementation?* `translate` is likely more complex than `replace`, as it does more. Why does this difference matter, though?

Comment: Translate expects a table (even though you're passing a null). At the very least, the extra checks (including I'm assuming a null check), will add some time.

Answer (score 25, accepted):

Assuming Python 2.7 (because I had to flip a coin without it being stated), we can find the source code for [string.translate](https://docs.python.org/2/library/string.html#string.translate) and [string.replace](https://docs.python.org/2/library/string.html#string.replace) in `string.py`:

```
>>> import inspect
>>> import string
>>> inspect.getsourcefile(string.translate)
'/usr/local/Cellar/python/2.7.9/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/string.py'
>>> inspect.getsourcefile(string.replace)
'/usr/local/Cellar/python/2.7.9/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/string.py'
>>>
```

Oh, we can't, `as string.py` starts with:

```
"""A collection of string operations (most are no longer used).

Warning: most of the code you see here isn't normally used nowadays.
Beginning with Python 1.6, many of these functions are implemented as
methods on the standard string object.
```

I upvoted you because you started down the path of profiling, so let's continue down that thread:

```
from cProfile import run
from string import ascii_letters

s = '1 a  2'

def _replace():
    for x in range(5000000):
        s.replace(' ', '')

def _translate():
    for x in range(5000000):    
        s.translate(None, ' ')
```

for replace:

```
run("_replace()")
         5000004 function calls in 2.059 seconds

   Ordered by: standard name

   ncalls  tottime  percall  cumtime  percall filename:lineno(function)
        1    0.976    0.976    2.059    2.059 <ipython-input-3-9253b3223cde>:8(_replace)
        1    0.000    0.000    2.059    2.059 <string>:1(<module>)
        1    0.000    0.000    0.000    0.000 {method 'disable' of '_lsprof.Profiler' objects}
  5000000    1.033    0.000    1.033    0.000 {method 'replace' of 'str' objects}
        1    0.050    0.050    0.050    0.050 {range}
```

and for translate:

```
run("_translate()")

         5000004 function calls in 1.785 seconds

   Ordered by: standard name

   ncalls  tottime  percall  cumtime  percall filename:lineno(function)
        1    0.977    0.977    1.785    1.785 <ipython-input-3-9253b3223cde>:12(_translate)
        1    0.000    0.000    1.785    1.785 <string>:1(<module>)
        1    0.000    0.000    0.000    0.000 {method 'disable' of '_lsprof.Profiler' objects}
  5000000    0.756    0.000    0.756    0.000 {method 'translate' of 'str' objects}
        1    0.052    0.052    0.052    0.052 {range}
```

our number of function calls are the same, not that more function calls means that a run will be slower, but it's typically a good place to look.  What's fun is that `translate` ran faster on my machine than `replace`!  Consider that the fun of not testing changes in isolation -- not that it matters because we only are concerned with being able to tell why there *could* be a difference.

In any case, we at least now know that there's maybe a performance difference and it does exist when evaluating the string object's method (see `tottime`).  The `translate` `__docstring__` suggests that there's a translation table in play, while the replace only mentions old-to-new-substring replacement.

Let's turn to our old buddy [`dis`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/dis.html) for hints:

```
from dis import dis
```

replace:

```
def dis_replace():
    '1 a  2'.replace(' ', '')

dis(dis_replace)


dis("'1 a  2'.replace(' ', '')")

  3           0 LOAD_CONST               1 ('1 a  2')
              3 LOAD_ATTR                0 (replace)
              6 LOAD_CONST               2 (' ')
              9 LOAD_CONST               3 ('')
             12 CALL_FUNCTION            2
             15 POP_TOP             
             16 LOAD_CONST               0 (None)
             19 RETURN_VALUE
```

and `translate`, which ran faster for me:

```
def dis_translate():
    '1 a  2'.translate(None, ' ')
dis(dis_translate)    


  2           0 LOAD_CONST               1 ('1 a  2')
              3 LOAD_ATTR                0 (translate)
              6 LOAD_CONST               0 (None)
              9 LOAD_CONST               2 (' ')
             12 CALL_FUNCTION            2
             15 POP_TOP             
             16 LOAD_CONST               0 (None)
             19 RETURN_VALUE
```

unfortunately, the two look identical to `dis`, which means that we should start looking to the string's C source here (found by going to the python source code for the version of Python I'm using right now)](https://hg.python.org/cpython/file/a887ce8611d2/Objects/stringobject.c).

Here's the [source for translate](https://hg.python.org/cpython/file/a887ce8611d2/Objects/stringobject.c#l2198).
If you go through the comments, you can see that there are multiple `replace` function definition lines, based on the length of the input.

Our options for substring replacement are:

[replace_substring_in_place](https://hg.python.org/cpython/file/a887ce8611d2/Objects/stringobject.c#l2552)

```
/* len(self)>=1, len(from)==len(to)>=2, maxcount>=1 */
Py_LOCAL(PyStringObject *)
replace_substring_in_place(PyStringObject *self,
```

and [replace_substring](https://hg.python.org/cpython/file/a887ce8611d2/Objects/stringobject.c#l2672):

```
/* len(self)>=1, len(from)>=2, len(to)>=2, maxcount>=1 */
Py_LOCAL(PyStringObject *)
replace_substring(PyStringObject *self,
```

and [replace_delete_single_character](https://hg.python.org/cpython/file/a887ce8611d2/Objects/stringobject.c#l2415):

```
/* Special case for deleting a single character */
/* len(self)>=1, len(from)==1, to="", maxcount>=1 */
Py_LOCAL(PyStringObject *)
replace_delete_single_character(PyStringObject *self,
                                char from_c, Py_ssize_t maxcount)
```

`'1 a  2'.replace(' ', '')` is a len(self)==6, replacing 1 char with an empty string, making it a `replace_delete_single_character`.

You can check out the function body for yourself, but the answer is "the C function body runs faster in `replace_delete_single_character` than `string_translate` for this specific input.

Thank you for asking this question.

Comment: Thank you for your insights and guidelines on profiling this problem. Especially `dis` module, which I wasn't aware of. I accept your answer as there isn't much to say about it. Digging to the very source of Python for me is good enough. Thank you again.

Comment: @NarūnasK Hey, really, thank you for asking this question -- it was deceivingly complex.  I had no idea that `replace` was dispatched to different functions.  I figured that it would be helpful to give you a little tour of how to dig into what Python is doing.

I was actually feeling bad for not going through the C functions to go more 'in-depth', but my lunch break ended.  Anyway, cheers!

Comment: @NarūnasK please re-read my answer.  I used `dis` incorrectly and cleaned up the answer to be more coherent.

Answer (score 6):

translate will likely be faster as N and M increase, where N is the number of unique character replacement maps, and M is the length of the string that is being translated.

```
import random
import string
import timeit
import re

def do_translation(N,M):
    trans_map = random.sample(string.ascii_lowercase,N),random.sample(string.ascii_lowercase,N)
    trans_tab = string.maketrans(*map("".join,trans_map))
    s = "".join(random.choice(string.ascii_lowercase) for _ in range(M))
    return s.translate(trans_tab)

def do_resub(N,M):
    trans_map = random.sample(string.ascii_lowercase,N),random.sample(string.ascii_lowercase,N)
    trans_tab = dict(zip(*trans_map))
    s = "".join(random.choice(string.ascii_lowercase) for _ in range(M))
    return re.sub("([%s])"%("".join(trans_map[0]),),lambda m:trans_tab.get(m.group(0),m.group(0)),s)

def do_replace(N,M):
    trans_map = random.sample(string.ascii_lowercase,N),random.sample(string.ascii_lowercase,N)
    s = "".join(random.choice(string.ascii_lowercase) for _ in range(M))
    for k,v in zip(*trans_map):
       s = s.replace(k,v)
    return s


data = {}
for i in range(2,20,2):
    for j in range(10,200,10):
        data[(i,j)] = {
            "translate":timeit.timeit("do_translation(%s,%s)"%(i,j),"from __main__ import do_translation,string,random",number=100),
            "re.sub":timeit.timeit("do_resub(%s,%s)"%(i,j),"from __main__ import do_resub,re,random",number=100),
            "replace":timeit.timeit("do_replace(%s,%s)"%(i,j),"from __main__ import do_replace,random",number=100)}

print data
```

will show you several different timings ... including that translate can be faster in several of these cases (I considered adding some plots here ... but ive already invested more time in this question than I really should have :P)

Comment: Why does translate become faster as the length of input increase?  Is there something in `dis` that's telling?