# Remove space from dictionary keys

Tags: python, dictionary

I have a dictionary with keys/values such as:

```
{'C  14': ['15263808', '13210478'], 'W   1': ['13122205']}
```

How can I remove the white space from all of the keys so they instead would be:

```
{'C14': ['15263808', '13210478'], 'W1': ['13122205']}
```

Comment: Do you want to edit the existing dictionary or create a new dictionary? Does anything need to be done about colliding keys?

Comment: All of the keys are unique, ideally the spaces would be removed from the existing dictionary keys.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

You can process all keys in a dictionary comprehension; you could use `str.translate()` to remove the spaces; the Python 2 version for that is:

```
{k.translate(None, ' '): v for k, v in dictionary.iteritems()}
```

and the Python 3 version is:

```
{k.translate({32: None}): v for k, v in dictionary.items()}
```

You could also use `str.replace()` to remove the spaces:

```
{k.replace(' ', ''): v for k, v in dictionary.items()}
```

But this may be slower for longer keys; see [Python str.translate VS str.replace](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31143290/python-str-translate-vs-str-replace)

Note that these produce a *new* dictionary.

Demo on Python 2:

```
>>> d = {'C  14': ['15263808', '13210478'], 'W   1': ['13122205']}
>>> {k.translate(None, ' '): v for k, v in d.iteritems()}
{'W1': ['13122205'], 'C14': ['15263808', '13210478']}
```

And a 2.6 compatible version (using [Alternative to dict comprehension prior to Python 2.7](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21069668/alternative-to-dict-comprehension-prior-to-python-2-7/21069676#21069676)):

```
dict((k.translate(None, ' '), v) for k, v in dictionary.iteritems())
```

Comment: What about `iteritems()` for the Python 2 version?

Comment: This is on Python 2.6.6 so dictionary comprehension isn't working

Comment: @GreyTek: then use [Alternative to dict comprehension prior to Python 2.7](https://stackoverflow.com/a/21069676)

Answer (score 4):

You can also just use `str.replace`:

```
In [4]: d = {'C  14': ['15263808', '13210478'], 'W   1': ['13122205']}

In [5]: d = {k.replace(" ",""): v for k,v in d.items()}

In [6]: d
Out[6]: {'C14': ['15263808', '13210478'], 'W1': ['13122205']}
```

For python2.6:

```
d = dict((k.replace(" ",""),v)  for k,v in d.items())
```

Comment: This is on Python 2.6.6 so dictionary comprehension isn't working

Comment: @GreyTek just replace it with a gen exp and a dict call

Answer (score 1):

Without dict comprehension:

```
>>> d = {'C  14': ['15263808', '13210478'], 'W   1': ['13122205']}
>>> dict(((k.replace(' ',''),v) for k,v in d.items()))
{'W1': ['13122205'], 'C14': ['15263808', '13210478']}
```

Comment: Drop the square brackets; no point in building a list first where a generator expression will do.

Answer (score 1):

Here's a solution without a `dict` comprehension, that edits the dictionary in-place, and assumes that no two old keys will map to the same new key.

```
d = {'C  14': ['15263808', '13210478'], 'W   1': ['13122205']}

for key in d.keys():
    if ' ' in key:
        d[key.translate(None, ' ')] = d[key]
        del d[key]

print d # {'W1': ['13122205'], 'C14': ['15263808', '13210478']}
```

After some timing, this is about 25% quicker than creating a new dictionary.

The loop iterates over `d.keys()` rather than `d` directly to avoid revisiting keys and avoid the whole "iterating over a changing object" issue.

Comment: Translate should actually be faster; perhaps I need to retime for single character replacements though.

Comment: @StevenRumbalski I fixed the deleting key issue, the author is using Python 2.6, so no need to consider Python 3.X.

Comment: See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/31143290/python-str-translate-vs-str-replace

Comment: @MartijnPieters From my tests, `replace` was running 1-2% faster than `translate` for a single character replacement in this scenario; good to know that in general `translate` will be faster.

Comment: Are your timsings still accurate with the updated code? Can you share your benchmark?

Comment: @MartijnPieters No, they are not still accurate, now `translate` is running about 3X faster than `replace`.