# Python insert a line break in a string after character "X"

Tags: python, list

What is the python syntax to insert a line break after every occurrence of character "X" ? This below gave me a list object which has no split attribute error

```
for myItem in myList.split('X'):
  myString = myString.join(myItem.replace('X','X\n'))
```

Comment: How could there be any X if you had split on X?

Answer (score 15, accepted):

```
myString = '1X2X3X'
print (myString.replace ('X', 'X\n'))
```

Answer (score 2):

**Python 3.X**

```
myString.translate({ord('X'):'X\n'})
```

`translate()` allows a dict, so, you can replace more than one different character at time.

Why `translate()` over `replace()` ? Check [translate vs replace](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31143290/python-str-translate-vs-str-replace)

**Python 2.7**

```
myString.maketrans('X','X\n')
```

Comment: @JacquesdeHooge ur welcome, I added a comparative between translate and replace.

Answer (score 2):

You can simply replace X by "X\n"

```
myString.replace("X","X\n")
```

Answer (score 1):

A list has no `split` method (as the error says).

Assuming `myList` is a list of strings and you want to replace `'X'` with `'X\n'` in each once of them, you can use list comprehension:

```
new_list = [string.replace('X', 'X\n') for string in myList]
```

Answer (score 1):

Based on your question details, it sounds like the most suitable is str.replace, as suggested by @DeepSpace. @levi's answer is also applicable, but could be a bit of a too big cannon to use.
I add to those an even more powerful tool - regex, which is slower and harder to grasp, but in case this is not really "X" -> "X\n" substitution you actually try to do, but something more complex, you should consider:

```
import re
result_string = re.sub("X", "X\n", original_string)
```

For more details: https://docs.python.org/2/library/re.html#re.sub