# Python 3 - How to continuously remove letters from a sentence?

Tags: python, python-3.x, ms-word

```
alphabet_dic = ['a','b','c','d','e','f','g','h','i','j','k','l','n','o','p','q','r','s','t','u','v','w','y','z','m']

doc = Document('test3.docx')
firstSen = doc.paragraphs[0].text
print (firstSen)

indexLetters = 0
while indexLetters < len(c_dic):
    d_dic = c_dic[indexLetters]
    indexLetters += 1
    secondSen = firstSen.replace(d_dic,"")    
    print (secondSen)
```

The test document holds the sentence "Hello There".
I am attempting to make a loop in where it checks the dictionary for a long range of specific letters and slowly loops and remove the letters from "Hello There".

Idea:

```
Sentence = Hello There

helloDic = ['h','e','l','o']

Desire Result = Tr
```

Any suggestions or better way to do this?

Answer (score 2):

Applying `str.replace` several times comes to mind at first, but it is really a non-performant method to do that ([Python str.translate VS str.replace](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31143290/python-str-translate-vs-str-replace))

As a nice alternative, you could modify your "dictionary" to create a real dictionary, compatible with `str.translate` (adding the uppercase letters too). Then you only have to apply the `str.translate` function to your string using the new dict:

```
Sentence = "Hello There"

helloDic = ['h','e','l','o']

rep_dic = {ord(k):None for k in helloDic + [x.upper() for x in helloDic]}

print(Sentence.translate(rep_dic))
```

result:

```
 Tr
```

(spaces were preserved)

Comment: Can't you use the `deletechars` argument provided in the `translate` method? `S.translate(table [,deletechars]) -> string`

Comment: `deletechars` is python 2 only. In python 3, you have to map your chars to `None`. Question is tagged "python 3"

Answer (score 0):

The straightforward solution

```
sentence = 'Hello There'

hello_dic = ['h','e','l','o']

r = [s for s in sentence if s.lower() not in hello_dic]

print ''.join(r)
```

Output

```
' Tr'
```

Comment: could be simplified by `s for s in sentence if s.lower() not in hello_dic` since `hello_dic` only contains lowercase letters.

Comment: and my turn to advise you to use `set` instead of `list`. For 4 letters it's no big a deal, though.