# Remove certain string from entire column in pandas dataframe

Tags: python, string, python-3.x, pandas, series

I have a pandas dataframe `df` with the contents below:

```
  Date          Factor       Expiry         Grade  
0 12/31/1991    2.138766     3/30/1992      -3.33% 
1 10/29/1992    2.031381     2/8/1993       -1.06% 
2 5/20/1993     2.075670     6/4/1993       -6.38%
```

I would like the remove the `%` character from all the rows in the `Grade` column. The result should look like this:

```
  Date          Factor     Expiry        Grade  
0 12/31/1991    2.138766   3/30/1992     -3.33 
1 10/29/1992    2.031381   2/8/1993      -1.06 
2 5/20/1993     2.075670   6/4/1993      -6.38
```

I am using Python v3.6.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You can use string slicing and then convert to a numeric type via [`pd.to_numeric`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.to_numeric.html):

```
df['Grade'] = pd.to_numeric(df['Grade'].astype(str).str[:-1], errors='coerce')
```

Conversion to `float` is recommended as a series of strings will be held in a generic and inefficient `object` dtype, while numeric types permit vectorised operations.

Comment: Thanks for the answer. Upvoted because I like the idea of converting to float. When I use your answer, I get the error `AttributeError: Can only use .str accessor with string values, which use np.object_ dtype in pandas`. I have no problem when I use `df['Grade'] = df['Grade'].str.replace('%', '')`.

Comment: @user3848207, Sure, you can convert to `str` in that case [as per my update].

Answer (score 24):

Using [`str.replace`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.Series.str.replace.html) would work:

```
df['Grade'] = df['Grade'].str.replace('%', '')
```

Answer (score 5):

Why not `str.rstrip()`:

```
df['Grade'] = df['Grade'].str.rstrip('%')
```

Answer (score 2):

So long as we are giving alternatives, can also `translate`

```
df.Grade.str.translate(str.maketrans({'%':''})).astype(float)
```

Comment: What would a practical *difference* be between `translate` and `replace`?

Comment: @BruceWayne I believe [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31143290/python-str-translate-vs-str-replace) has answers more complete than I could post in a comment here ;)